# Concatenate strings in pairs?

Tags: r

I am trying to concatenate strings in pairs.

Here is what I am doing:

```
paste(c("C","S"), seq(1,5), sep="")
```

The result is:

```
C1, S2, C3, S4, C5
```

The result I want is:

```
C1, S1, C2, S2, C3, S3, C4, S4, C5, S5
```

Comment: `c(outer(c("C","S"), 1:5, paste0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paste0(c("C","S"), rep(1:5, each=2))
```

Comment: This did it. I did not realize rep had an each parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important, you can try this:

```
paste(sort(paste(c("C","S"),rep(seq(1,5),2), sep = "")), collapse = ", ")
```

And you will get this result:

```
C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5
```